# Is it possible to get parent object while inserting into database using sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I Want to insert comments in database but in response i also want to get the user object of the child. How do i do it using sequelize? I am using postgreSQL as database.

This is comments model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Comments = sequelize.define("Comments", {
    commentBody: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });
  Comments.associate = (models) => {
    Comments.belongsTo(models.Users, {
      foreignKey: "UserId",
      onDelete: "cascade",
    });
  };
  return Comments;
};
```

This is Users Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Users = sequelize.define("Users", {
    fullName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
  });

  Users.associate = (models) => {
    Users.hasMany(models.Posts, {
      onDelete: "cascade",
    });
    Users.hasMany(models.Comments, {
      onDelete: "cascade",
    });
    Users.hasMany(models.Likes, {
      onDelete: "cascade",
    });
  };

  return Users;
};
```

i want to get user object in savedComment. Some what like this

> {id:1,...,Users:{id:1,username:username,...}}

I tried the following

```
try {
    const comment = req.body;
    const id = req.user.id;
    comment.UserId = id;
    const savedComment = await Comments.create(comment, {
      include: { model: Users },
    });
    res.status(200).json(savedComment);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
```

but i only got comment's object not Users inside it